# Disable Knexjs Migrations?

Tags: knex.js

We are using Knexjs already on our API and it needs to connect to another data source where migrations are handled separately. However for this connection using Knexjs I want to disable running any migrations but I can't see to find any official way to do so.

Right now I have hacked it a bit by configuration the migration directory just for this knexjs connection to an empty directory and setting a validation flag to false.

Is there any official way to say, don't try and do any migration?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable transactions for all migrations via the common migration config option `config.disableTransactions` or per-migration, via exposing a boolean property `config.transaction` from a migration file.

```
exports.up = function(knex) {
  return knex.schema
    .createTable('users', function (table) {
        table.increments('id');
        table.string('first_name', 255).notNullable();
        table.string('last_name', 255).notNullable();
    })
    .createTable('products', function (table) {
        table.increments('id');
        table.decimal('price').notNullable();
        table.string('name', 1000).notNullable();
    });
};

exports.down = function(knex) {
  return knex.schema
      .dropTable("products")
      .dropTable("users");
};

exports.config = { transaction: false };
```